# Is it possible to create archetypes in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, templates, gradle, archetypes

Is it possible to create a Gradle archetype and then create a Gradle project based on the archetype?
Just like in Maven.

I want to create a Scala or Java archetype for other developers to use as a starting point.

I currently only have an initial template in Gradle with the folder structure and initial sample startup code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't inherit support however there is a plugin available on GitHub. Haven't used it but it does look promising, last update was a few months ago.

https://github.com/orctom/gradle-archetype-plugin